# dotnet core dispatcher for observablecollection

Tags: c#, .net-core

.Net Core has Threading/Tasks and ObservableCollection, but no dispatcher service that I can find.

How can I update an ObservableCollection from .net core from another thread?

In Wpf I can use dispatcher service and winform has similar possibilities.

Thanks

...

Edit 1:

The idea with .net core is cross platform, so there is not dedicated framework or target. It could be used in Wpf, android (xamarin), asp.net, linux(mono)...

Edit 2:
Xamarin has a solution Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread, but I am looking for net Core. https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread/p/System.Action/

Comment: Can you add details about the design that you are trying to achieve? What framework are you using? Is this ASP.net?

Comment: The general mechanism that abstracts over all of these is `SynchronizationContext.Post`, but as far as I know Core does not supply its own implementation. (If it does, it'd probably be something that uses the thread pool.)

Comment: @Gusdor there is no target framework

Comment: @user1714341 if you are not targeting any application framework, what is the requirement for serializing access to a collection? -1

Comment: @Gusdor I do not understand what you are asking. are you talking about io serialization or displaying the data on a user interface?

Comment: @user1714341 access serialisation is what the wpf dispatcher and winforms message pumps achieve. Messages are posted onto the UI thread and handled serially (one after another, as a stream of messages)

Comment: @Gusdor I am actually trying to avoid deep discussions and was hoping someone has come across this problem. Guess I will have to wait. I found that Xamarin has something, but I need it for .net core. Thanks anyhow

Comment: @user1714341 Good luck. You are not listening to your betters. Don't expect the answer you _want_ to see.

Comment: @user1714341: If you have tasks, then the standard approach is to let the client decide where the task should be executed and leverage `TaskScheduler`. See [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/part_5_-_practical_code_sharing_strategies/), at "parallel task library". The general point is: since your client knows what framework is being used, don't make your library depend on the details. If a task needs to be executed on the UI, let the client create the task with defaults and it will be posted back by default.

Comment: @Gusdor I am sorry for offending you, but I am trying to keep to stackoverflow's guidelines found here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks, I will look into TaskScheduler. It make sense that the client/target platform will remain responsible for threading.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jeroen suggestion. I ended up with the follow code:

```
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // Do some process
        }).ContinueWith(x =>
        {
           // Update ObservableCollection here
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```